# How do I map multiple functions over a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

It's come to this:

How do I map multiple functions over a list?

```
items = ['this', 'that', 100]
item_types = (type(i) for i in items)
items_gen = map(next(item_types), items)
```

This does not work, neither do many other things I've tried.
What am I missing?

I get either the first type mapped all over the entire list, or the type applied to the first item and itself cut into character snippets...

If this is a dupe - sorry, can't find this question in any reasonable way being asked here due to a million ways being asked.

I am going to switch out the items for input()'s so this is just a crude example, but I want to apply types to input values.

Expected output:
I want to call next on this item_gen object and get: 'this', 'that', 100
Not: 'this', 'that', '100'

Comment: What do you mean by multiple functions? Could you provide the expected output?

Comment: Added. As far as I can tell I want it to map str, str, int. Based on the item_types generator values.

Comment: Still unclear what you want, but how does this fail: `items_gen = (type(i)(i) for i in items)`.  That is, apply `type(i)` _immediately_ upon obtaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[see EDIT below]
I think you need one more generator in the chain, if this is what you're looking for, a type conversion (or verification?) system?

```
def mapper(typedefs, target):
    igen = (i for i in typedefs)
    item_types = (type(i) for i in igen)
    return map(next(item_types), target)
```

so then if you say:

```
list(mapper(['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]))
```

You'd get:

```
['1','2','3']
```

This will throw ValueError exceptions in the reverse conversion, however.

[EDIT]: that's incorrect above. This looks good:

```
def foo(types, target):
    if len(types) == len(target):
        gen1 = (type(i) for i in types)
        gen2 = ([i] for i in target)   #key is make this a list
        gen3 = (next(map(next(gen1),next(gen2))) for _ in types)
        yield from gen3
```

Now we get item-by-item type conversion (attempts):

```
bar = foo(['a',True,3.14,1],[1,1,1,1]))
list(bar)
['1',True,1.0,1]
```

Comment: If only it were that easy. Try to insert a mixed variety of types, like str, int, str. Your mapper did the same thing - mapped the first item type for the entire list of items. The problem lies in the next(item_types).

Comment: Ouch, right you are. I spent a little time on it and came up with something that seems to work.

Comment: Can you explain the significance of gen2? It creates a generator which will iterate on next each item separately from initial target list, right?

*** I was really going the correct direction because I knew that both the types and target needed to be generators and be called with next though.

Finally - finished! Thanks, @neutrino_logic!

Comment: @VaidøtasIvøška gen2 works with map(func, iterable) because it generates a list of one element (for each element in the original list) as the iterable. So ```next(map(int, ['12']))``` spits out ```12```. Here gen1 and gen2 steadily feed map with new suitable inputs, and gen3 pumps out a new map object on each cycle. ```yield from``` allows the gen3 generator to be cycled through (every other method seems to fail, which I don't quite understand).

Comment: I was hasty to say that it is all finished, because tuple type objects fail at the moment, screwing up the next in line items to be transformed. I did fix the NoneType issue with an additional list comprehension, and I had another working solution yet ctrl-z'd too much into oblivion for a bit. One really nasty thing is an item in types: (100,), because the input is accompanied with a ' split(', ')' further complicating things. But you helped a lot with this ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can just zip 2 iterable and apply each function to each element. Example:

```
>>> def f1(x): return x+1
... 
>>> def f2(x): return x+2
... 
>>> def f3(x): return x+3
... 
>>> functions = [f1,f2,f3]
>>> elements = [1,1,1]
>>> [f(el) for f,el in zip(functions,elements)]
[2, 3, 4]
```

Which in your case becomes:

```
>>> [f(el) for f,el in zip(item_types,items)]
['this', 'that', 100]
```

Comment: This looks promising, though I need this to be a generator function that outputs these converted values one at a time, due to other functionalities. Also - this requires creating arbitrary functions, relisting them in a list comprehension and I need this as dynamic as possible as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

To use `map` here, you need to map *function application*. then, you can use the multi-argument form of `map`, something like:

```
>>> funcs = [lambda x: x+1, lambda x: x*2, lambda x: x**3]
>>> data = [1, 2, 3]
>>> def apply(f, x): return f(x)
...
>>> list(map(apply, funcs, data))
[2, 4, 27]
```

Note, passing `next(item_types)` makes no sense, that gives you the next item in `item_types`, which in this case, is the first type, if you want to understand what you were seeing before.

Or, with your example:

```
>>> items = ['this', 'that', 100]
>>> list(map(apply, map(type, items), items))
['this', 'that', 100]
```

Comment: You mean: list(map(apply(funcs, data)))? Right?

Comment: @VaidøtasIvøška no, that doesn't make any sense. `apply(funcs, data)` would raise a `TypeError`, because `funcs` is a `list` and `list` objects aren't callable. Did you try typing in the code I've shown above (which is from a REPL session?)

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want to do is create a generator out of a list (I am not sure what the whole `type` thing there is for).

To do just that you can just call `iter`:

```
item_gen = iter(items)
res = []
res.append(next(item_gen))
res.append(next(item_gen))
res.append(next(item_gen))
print(res)
```

will print (and the types will be the original ones):

> ['this', 'that', 100]

Assuming you have just one set of types in a `types` list and you want them to get applied you can do the following thing:

```
types = [str, str, int]
item_gen = (tp(i) for tp, i in zip(types, items))
```

Comment: The type thing is me trying to create a type conversion mapping function. Due to there being a mixed set of default values for each input instead of the placeholder items list - I need to apply a different type map for each item in the items list. If you can show how to add that to your example - I'd like to see it.